# Cnext command : how to move to xxx item?

Tags: vim

So when I use grep command to search for a specific word, and open it the with `copen` command (`quickfix` window), I am able to move item by `:cnext` and `:cprevious`. But what if there are 7000 items ? (for example searching for word **if**). Then of course are thousand of files containing "if" statement. Is there a way to move to a specific item? As possible to move to a specific line like `42G` to move to 42 line?

Also in `quickfix` window I am able to move by lines `jk` keys (as in any other buffers), but when i move to another item by these keys (NOT with `:cnext` or `:cprevious`), how can I **open** it? (by `:cnext` or `:cprevious` it opens automaticly to original buffer, so how to open an quickfix item with "moveble" keys?)

Answer (score 3):

See https://vimhelp.org/quickfix.txt.html

To move to the 42'nd line in the quickfix list:

```
:42cnext
```

To open an entry from the quickfix window just press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: when i pres <cr> then error arise: "cannot make changes, 'modifiable' is off

Comment: Strange. Works for me. I ran `vimgrep`, `copen` to open the quickfix window, pressed `Enter` — `vim` moved the cursor to the corresponding line/column. What is the type of buffer that reports the error? `:echo &buftype`? For me it's `quickfix`.

Comment: for me the same - quickfix as a &buftype, however i use :grep! instead of :vimgrep which I suppose is a internal searching (as described in documentation), and :grep should be normal command from bash (the same utility), but this shouldnt be the reason. But still when press enter to next file , "cannot make changes, 'modifiable' is off" appears.

Comment: I just tried `:grep` and `:copen` — everything works as expected.

Comment: @phd's soultion works for me too. what is `verbose set ma?` gives for you